# What does the file app.json do?

Tags: javascript, slack

I stumbled upon this repository https://github.com/sparragus/slack-bot-edward-snowden when I was learning to write a bot for Slack. I saw app.json among the files and had no idea of its purpose. Can someone tell me what purpose this app.json file serve in this and other similar scenarios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> app.json is a manifest format for describing web apps. It declares environment variables, add-ons, and other information required to run an app on Heroku. This document describes the schema in detail.

— https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema

Comment: Is it possible to declare the `success_url` via the CLI? (I know buildpacks can be set that way, not so sure about `success_url` though)